# Problems acessing site via domain

Tags: dns, ip-address, windows, ping

I recently used a windows server to host a node js website somewhat successfully. I then tried to associate the website to the domain name I had on Go Daddy. I just substituted the IP address in the name field. I was waiting for the website to load (it has been 1 day) but it doesn't work with the domain name, it gives "Request timed out", but when I try accessing it via IP I can see the website. I tried pinging both the domain and IP and they showed "Request timed out".

This is my go daddy account configuration:

[image]

Can anyone help me identify the issue?

Comment: I can't see the site if I use the IP address. Is the server still up?  Is there a firewall?  Where can you access it from?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller it is still up. The server provider imposed a security rule to only allow a few countries in (Europe), maybe that's why you can't see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. There were 2 main issues. I think my go daddy setup was not ok, so I re-did it as you can see in the image.

[image]

Also there was a cache issue, after I cleaned it everything was ok.

Comment: It looks like you changed the record for the `www` subdomain from `CNAME` to an `A` record.  It was fine to do that, but it shouldn't have made a difference to the problem you were having.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller maybe just the cache made the trick. But by then I had already changed the go daddy settings also.

Answer (score 0):

Trying flushing your DNS cache on Windows, open command prompt and type this:

`ipconfig /flushdns`

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but it didn't change anything